# Any (n-1) vectors from system X are linearly independent $\nRightarrow$ X is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let X denote system of n vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any (n-1) vectors from X are linearly independent.

Claim: the system X is linearly independent.

I need a counterexample, because the claim should be false (I have answers, but not solutions). But I have difficulties in constructing it.

Take (n-1) linearly independent vectors. To make the whole system linearly dependent, we clearly need to add some linear combination of (n-1) vectors. But then, drop the any vector from initial (n-1) vectors and consider what is left. Clearly, we have linearly dependent (n-1) vectors which contradicts to the premise.

So, either my reasoning is flawed, or the claim is true.

Comment: Here's a counterexample for $n=2$. :) Take the two vectors $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$.

Comment: "To make the whole system linearly dependent, we clearly need to add some linear combination of (n-1) vectors" - of n vectors not n-1 vectors

Comment: Teh flaw is in "Clearly, we have linearly dependent (n-1) vectors". Think about the "clearly" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $n-1$ linear independent vectors $v_1\dots v_{n-1}$. Set $v_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} v_i$. Then $X=\{v_1\dots v_n\}$ fulfills the assumptions: $X$ is linear dependent, but any $n-1$ vectors are linearly independent.

To see this, let me prove that $v_2\dots v_{n}$ are linearly independent:
Then $\sum_{i=2}^{n}\lambda_iv_i=0$ implies
$$
\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} (\lambda_i+\lambda_n) v_i + \lambda_nv_1=0.
$$
Now the vectors $v_1\dots v_n$ are linearly independent, then $\lambda_n=0$, and $\lambda_i=0$, $i=2\dots n-1$ follows.

Answer (score 4):

Take the vectors $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Wow, could please explain, what went wrong in my solution?

Comment: @Mirak: I'am sorry, but I do not understand you argumentation very well. But its wrong to suggest, that to make the (n-1) linearly independent system a basis you need to add a linear combination of those (n-1) vectors. In fact with no addition of a linear combination of the (n-1) vectors you will get a basis in the end...